# "Our advertisers want to know..." Redux

Tags: discussion, advertising

Way back in February of 2011, a long-time Stack Overflow advertiser asked to run an ad campaign to learn more about our users. Their method of delivery: a survey.

Surveys can be a tricky campaign for the Ad Sales team at Stack Exchange. We require ads to clearly display the company responsible for them (no surprises!), but preventing bias is often vital to the success of a survey. Including a logo on the creative will, of course, expose the advertiser-- thus rendering the survey results useless.

Back in the good old days of 2011 We ran the campaign and notified the community with a [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/our-advertisers-want-to-know/). This time around, I'm here to inform you that an advertiser is once again running a survey campaign, and it is happening *right now.* This is another Stack Exchange advertiser who we've had a positive relationship with for years. Just like last time, we have some points to highlight for you:

- This is a real survey, it is not spam.
- This survey is targeting only users in the United States-- sorry international peeps! This is for ease of reward fulfillment purposes.
- Survey official rules located [here](http://bit.ly/StackOverflowSurveyOfficialRules).
- Please do not disclose the name of the advertiser here if you figure it out. It compromises the validity of the survey and I'll just have to write another post on Meta and no one really wants that, right?
- If you have any questions about the survey, post them as answers to this question.

The ad you will see is below:
[image: survey-creative-20150302]

**TL;DR: there is an SE-approved survey campaign running on Stack Overflow. Survey official rules [here](http://bit.ly/StackOverflowSurveyOfficialRules).**

Comment: You might want to poke Shog or someone to give you an SE diamond here ([you have one on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/178809/))... as it is, it can be confusing... at 0th glance, you appear to be a random low rep user rather than what I now see (when digging into your profile) "Ad Ops @ StackHQ" (and a MSE diamond which can only be SE types).

Comment: @MichaelT already on it. So many sites to have a diamond on, so little time...

Comment: That looks better... while you're at it... want to give me one? ( ;-)... I promise to 'fix' the close vote review queue [after I learn me some Haskell](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=12599256#12599256).

Comment: @MichaelT While I dream to one day have the power to give and take almighty diamonds, alas, that day is not yet upon us. :-p

Comment: @MichaelT I nominate you for all-encompassing-evil-SE-overlord, "destroyer of all low quality posts"

Comment: erm, don't the survey rules kinda give away the sponsor?  Granted, ***no one*** reads the official rules, but, you know....

Comment: @GlenH7 SHHHHHHHH

Comment: Ooh, ooh, I guessed who the advertiser is. Do I get the $300 Amazon Gift voucher now? Please, I did guess it right!

Comment: @MartijnPieters You get a high five, personally, from me. Which is worth waaaaay less than the Amazon gift card. You're practically paying for it.

Comment: @stevvve: wait, what, you are not forking out for the plane ticket from the UK to NY for me to be able to collect that high five?! I am disappoint.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was leaning toward coming out to the UK, but...

Comment: ***Why isn't that image clickable???***

Comment: @stevvve: that *may* be an acceptable alternative. If you do [bring presents](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88469/help-us-make-a-stack-overflow-beer-stein) though. I may even provide the fluids to fill 'em.

Comment: TLDR : remember that while *one* lucky soul will win a $300 gift card, the company behind the survey will make way more money from *each* one of you. So you may want to think twice before voluntarily surrendering the little bit of privacy you have left.

Comment: The rules require registering for Microsoft OneDrive? *Seriously*?

Comment: @AndrewMedico I can read them just fine, no registration required.  I haven't interacted with OneDrive before.  Perhaps you have some leftover state in your browser from a past interaction?

Comment: Has anyone actually proof read the survey, the questions dont feel like they were written by a web dev, and there are grammar mistakes...

Answer (score -6):

The survey spammed me long before your message here was posted. So you're a day late and a dollar short.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I literally pressed the button within 20 seconds of posting this question on Meta.

Comment: Sometime over the weekend I visited some SE site and got hit by a giant survey banner.

Comment: That is likely for the Braintree contest-- unrelated to this one.